# IF and else Windows Script

Tags: windows, if-statement, scripting

The following is my code but it keeps giving me the `error: else was unexpected at this time`.

```
@echo on
:Install_Language
reg query "hklm\system\controlset001\control\nls\language" /v Installlanguage | FIND "0409"
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
        Echo English
        ) else (
    reg query "hklm\system\controlset001\control\nls\language" /v Installlanguage | FIND "040c"
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
        Echo French 1
        )
    )   else (
            reg query "hklm\system\controlset001\control\nls\language" /v Installlanguage | FIND "0C0C"
        IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
        Echo French2
        )
    )
```

Comment: Sami, you should accept answers when they're useful.

Comment: Thanks Vland, I usually do, I am not sure why i didn't this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see only one of these can be true, so this should work.

```
@echo on
:Install_Language
reg query "hklm\system\controlset001\control\nls\language" /v Installlanguage | FIND "0409" > nul && Echo English
reg query "hklm\system\controlset001\control\nls\language" /v Installlanguage | FIND "040c" > nul && Echo French 1
reg query "hklm\system\controlset001\control\nls\language" /v Installlanguage | FIND "0C0C" > nul && Echo French2
```